# Error in Building WebScraper: TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, google-api, web-scraping

Am building a webscraper that displays top urls for web trends. However am always returned with the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Ceryx\webSearch.py", line 21, in <module>
    topl=webScraper(m)
  File "D:\Ceryx\webSearch.py", line 12, in webScraper
    hot = data['results'][0]['url']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Help!!

```
import re
import json
import urllib, urllib2

def webScraper(trends):
    query=urllib.urlencode({'q':trends})
    url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&%s' % query
    response = urllib.urlopen(url)
    extract = response.read()
    results = json.loads(extract)
    data = results['responseData']
    hot = data['results'][0]['url']
    return hot

response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends/atom/hourly')
html = response.read()
matchObj = re.findall(r'<a[^>]*?>(.*?)</a>', html)

print "Urls"
for m in matchObj:
    topl=webScraper(m)
    print m,topl
```

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Working fine here with `v2.7.2`

Comment: i suspect its a problem due to deprecation of the google search api, try running it the second/third time. Reckon once the search limit has been exhausted the IP address is blocked from further queries.

Answer (score 1):

The error is on this line:

```
hot = data['results'][0]['url']
```

And it means that one of the following are `None`

```
data
data['results']
data['results'][0]
```

You can find out which one by printing in succession:

```
print 'data',data
print 'data[results]',data['results']
print 'data[results][0]',data['results'][0]
```

Then the million dollar question will be how you ended up with that in your `json` in the first place -- And figuring out what you need to do to handle it (or prevent it if you have control over these things).  :)